# Parse JSON response with numbers as Object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have this JSON response, from a remote server and i really hope i can get help.

```
{
  "data": {
    "6111": {
      "prereq": "0",
      "mast": "The Master Tree"
    },
    "6112": {
      "prereq": "1",
      "mast": "Another Master Tree"
    }
  }
}
```

I use GSON to parse JSON, using the `@SerializedName` and `@Expose`to obtain the value into a custom Model. But i do not understand how to get past the

> "6111"
>   "6112"

I have checked other questions via the `gson` tag, to no avail.

Comment: {
"6111": 
  { 
     "prereq": "0",
     "mast": "The Master Tree"
  },
"6112":
  {
    "prereq": "1",
     "mast": "Another Master Tree"
  }
}  this should be json array

Comment: It's unclear if these are dynamic. Being numeric I would imagine so, but what's stopping you just looping over the array to get the content?

Comment: Thats the thing, it is not an array, as the [] would have signified it as such. Its an object, but i trying to understand if there is a method of GSON that supports 'Incosistent key/value pairs'.

Comment: asked bazillion times ... use Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

///////////////////update////////////////////

```
   JSONObject issueObj = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
Iterator iterator = issueObj.keys();
   while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String key = (String)iterator.next();
    JSONObject issue = issueObj.getJSONObject(key);

    //  get id from  issue
        String _pubKey = issue.optString("id");
    }
```

Comment: Okay, and how do i list out the information in each Object?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gson, any time you have an object with keys you don't know ahead of time, you can just use `Map` instead of a custom object.

In this case, each element of the `Map` will be some "known" data structure, so you would use `Map<String, MyObject>`.

Your top-level class:

```
public class MyResponse {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, MyObject> data;

    ...
}
```

And your map's value class:

```
public class MyObject {

    @SerializedName("prereq")
    @Expose
    private String prereq;

    @SerializedName("mast")
    @Expose
    private String mast;

    ...
}
```

In the specific case of the json text you posted, you would then be able to use these objects like this:

```
response.getData().get("6111").getMast();
```

But you can also do anything you could normally do with a `Map`:

```
Map<String, MyObject> data = response.getData();

for (String key: data.keySet() {
    ...
}

for (MyObject obj : data.values()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: There are more "6111" Map objects, i am looking to list (using RecyclerView) them all, rather than binding their values to widgets like TextView. Using the `response.getData().get("6111").getMast();` is very good, how can add the objects' values to an adapter?.

Comment: @JendorskiLabs what is the real meaning of the `"6111"` key? Is it an id or something? It could be the case that you'd be better off processing the `response.getData()` map into a new data structure before handing it off to the rest of your app. Regardless, you could always write code like `List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>(response.getData().values())` and then pass that list to a recyclerview adapter as normal.

Comment: Thanks for this, i used Iteration to get the `mast` out of the `6111` keys, the JSON is from a remote server and i had no idea on how to add the JSON to `Map`, all i saw on several SOs were `map.put(key, Model)`. The first answer works well with the idea to use the `List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>(response.getData().values())` and pass the list to a recyclerView adapter.